# Python error in class

Tags: python, self

```
class exampleclass:     
    def meth01(self, name):         
        print self.name

obj1 = exampleclass()
obj1.meth01("James")
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in
<module>
    obj1.meth01("James")   File "<pyshell#3>", line 3, in meth01
    print self.name AttributeError: exampleclass instance has no attribute 'name'
```

So what have I done wrong to produce this error, the name is in the parameters And I tried to set what name was so that it could print?

Comment: You need to first set the `self.name`.

Comment: @Kasra Please don't add "please" and "thanks" etc. to questions.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Why? Surely because name is in the parameters and has yet to be defined I can when define it when an object is created? I'm trying to figure out the purpose of writing self.name = name if i were to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing `self.name`. This is a member variable of the class, not the input variable of the function `meth01`. In your function `name` refers to the input, and `self.name` refers to a member variable of the class. But you are not setting it.

Do this instead:

```
class ExampleClass:
    def meth01(self, name):
        print( name )
```

To understand what is going on, expand it like this:

```
class ExampleClass:
    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def meth01(self, name):
        print('Input variable name: ', name)
        print('Member variable name: ', self.name)

 ec = ExampleClass()
 ec.meth01('John') # This line will fail because ec.name hasn't been set yet.
 ec.setName('Jane')
 ec.meth01('John')
 # This will print:
 #('Input variable name: ', 'John')
 #('Member variable name: ', 'Jane')
```

Comment: @Unapidra , member variable of the class? can you explain what that means? I am trying to understand why people write, self.name = name ? It makes no sense, what is self.name it seems to be a method because of the dot but its not ? also why do we need to put it inside name ? and is that the same "name" as the one in the parameter? me head is about to explode.

Comment: @Grey, are you familiar with Object Oriented Programming? A member variable is a variable that belongs to a class. In Python member variables and functions/methods are referred to by the dot. No parentheses so it is a variable.

Comment: The `name` and `self.name` are two completely different things! `def meth01(self, not_a_name): self.name = not_a_name`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your `__init__` method

```
class exampleclass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Answer (score 1):

A variable `name` is part of the parameter list, but there's no `name` member value in the example class object itself (yet).

Think of what your code does, step by step. First it instantiates a new `exampleclass` object.

You then call `obj1.meth01("James")`. `meth01` is passed with the values self = obj1 and name="James"

`meth01` then tries to find a value stored as `obj1.name`, but none exists, since in this case `name` is local to the method `meth01` and is not part of the object `obj01` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a `constructor` that is used to initialise an object.

Make your `__init__` method like this.

```
class exampleclass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

NOTE: Declare the constructor as mentioned only.

You can understand `self` like this:

Self stores the address of the object from which the constructor or method is called.
So self.name=name would result in assigning the data member of the object from which it is called to the variable `name` which is passed as parameter to the constructor.